# Distinct aggregation: need help to write a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Question was edited, because `SUM(DISTINCT(num_profiles))` not a solution!

Let's say I have a table (ExampleData):

```
+----------+---------------+-----------+------+--------------+------------+
| date     | function_name | file_name | self | num_profiles | profile_id |
+----------+---------------+-----------+------+--------------+------------+
| 20190301 | function1     | file1.go  | 10   | 30           | 100        |
| 20190301 | function2     | file1.go  | 20   | 30           | 100        |
| 20190301 | function1     | file1.go  | 30   | 20           | 200        |
| 20190301 | function3     | file1.go  | 40   | 20           | 200        |
| 20190301 | function4     | file1.go  | 45   | 20           | 222        |
| 20190301 | function1     | file2.go  | 50   | 20           | 200        |
| 20190302 | function1     | file1.go  | 10   | 10           | 300        |
| 20190302 | function2     | file1.go  | 20   | 10           | 300        |
| 20190302 | function3     | file2.go  | 60   | 10           | 300        |
+----------+---------------+-----------+------+--------------+------------+
```

And I need to aggregate by date, file_name and calculate sum(self) and sum(num_profiles). Something like this:

```
SELECT
    date,
    file_name,
    SUMself) AS self,
    SUM(num_profiles) AS num_profiles
FROM ExampleData 
GROUP BY date, file_name 
ORDER BY date, file_name;
```

But **I need to modify logic** of `sum(num_profiles) as num_profiles`. I need to summarize `num_profile`s only with different `profile_ids`.
Instead of:

```
+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
| date     | file_name | self | num_profiles |
+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
| 20190301 | file1.go  | 145  | 120          |
| 20190301 | file2.go  | 50   | 20           |
| 20190302 | file1.go  | 30   | 20           |
| 20190302 | file2.go  | 60   | 10           |
+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
```

I need to have this result:

```
+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
| date     | file_name | self | num_profiles |
+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
| 20190301 | file1.go  | 145  | 70           |
| 20190301 | file2.go  | 50   | 20           |
| 20190302 | file1.go  | 30   | 10           |
| 20190302 | file2.go  | 60   | 10           |
+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
```

The first row is a result of aggregation:

```
+----------+---------------+-----------+------+--------------+------------+
| date     | function_name | file_name | self | num_profiles | profile_id |
+----------+---------------+-----------+------+--------------+------------+
| 20190301 | function1     | file1.go  | 10   | 30           | 100        |
| 20190301 | function2     | file1.go  | 20   | 30           | 100        |
| 20190301 | function1     | file1.go  | 30   | 20           | 200        |
| 20190301 | function4     | file1.go  | 45   | 20           | 222        |
| 20190301 | function3     | file1.go  | 40   | 20           | 200        |
+----------+---------------+-----------+------+--------------+------------+
```

`self = sum(aggregated self)` - this is what I need.
But `num_profiles` should be the sum from the rows with different `profile_ids` (30(profile_id=100) + 20(profile_id=200) +20(profile_id=222)=70).
Like this:

```
SELECT SUM(num_profiles)
FROM (
    SELECT ANY_VALUE(num_profiles) AS num_profiles
    FROM ExampleData 
    WHERE date='20190301' AND file_name='file1.go' 
    GROUP BY profile_id
);
```

This example calculates `num_profiles` for the first row.
In my dataset `num_profile`s for particular `profile_id` are the same.

How can I combine this logic into the single query?

Comment: how you define which profile id you need incase of duplicate like 100 has two records which one you need

Comment: As I have mentioned in the end of the post "In my dataset num_profiles for particular profile_id are the same". So, doesn't matter which num_profiles will be taken for example for profile_id=100 (all num_profiles will be equal/same).

profile_id needs only for custom calculation sum(num_profiles).

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an odd request (hence interesting as well). I think that to solve this you would need to perform a first level of aggregation in subqueries, join the resultsets together, and aggregate a second time.

Consider:

```
SELECT
  e1.date,
  e1.file_name,
  e1.sum_self as self,
  SUM(e2.num_profiles) as num_profiles
FROM 
    (
        SELECT date, file_name, SUM(self) as sum_self
        FROM ExampleData
        GROUP BY date, file_name
    ) e1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT date, file_name, num_profiles, profile_id FROM ExampleData
    ) e2 ON e2.date = e1.date AND e2.file_name = e1.file_name
GROUP BY e1.date, e1.file_name, e1.sum_self
ORDER BY e1.date, e1.file_name;
```

In **[this DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xrtk4zBNRTQyirpSd76WFV/0)** with your sample data, this query returns:

```
| date       | file_name | self | num_profiles |
| ---------- | --------- | ---- | ------------ |
| 2019-03-01 | file1.go  | 100  | 50           |
| 2019-03-01 | file2.go  | 50   | 20           |
| 2019-03-02 | file1.go  | 30   | 10           |
| 2019-03-02 | file2.go  | 60   | 10           |
```

Comment: Yes. Looks like it returns correct result. But I am worrying about performance.

Comment: @dhythhsba: actually I did try to make it simpler... But given your assignment, I could not come up with something shorter than this. I am afraid all other answers just won't produce the result you expect...

Comment: If you worry about performance you could set up an index on `ExampleData(date, file_name, num_profiles, profile_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum(distinct column):

```
SELECT
  date,
  file_name,
  sum(self) as self,
  sum(distinct num_profiles) as num_profiles
FROM ExampleData 
GROUP BY date, file_name 
ORDER BY date, file_name
```

After the clarification for the profile_id requirement and better date the simplest way to do the query would be:

```
select e.date,
  e.file_name,
  sum(e.self) as self,
  sum(e.num_profiles) as num_profiles
from (
  select date, file_name, profile_id, 
     sum(self) as self, sum(distinct num_profiles) as num_profiles
  from ExampleData
  group by date, file_name, profile_id
) as e
group by e.date, e.file_name
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ab48b/15)

Comment: num_profiles can be the same for different profile_id. And in this case it should be summarized several times.

Comment: Edit your data to reflect this and show the expected output.

Comment: I have added more example data to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but you can use SUM(DISTINCT)

```
SELECT
  date,
  file_name,
  sum(self) as self,
  sum(DISTINCT num_profiles) as num_profiles
FROM ExampleData GROUP BY date, file_name ORDER BY date, file_name;
```

Typically we use DISTINCT with COUNT (to count the number of different values), but it will work with SUM as well.

Comment: I have added more example data to the question. Your solution returns wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

You can summarize distinct profiles of files having more than 1 different profile ids on a specific date using below

```
SELECT
date,
file_name,
sum(self) as self,     
sum(distinct num_profiles) 
 as 
 num_profiles
FROM ExampleData GROUP BY
 date,file_name Order By
 date,file_name
 Having count(distinct 
  profile_id) >1
```

Comment: I have added more example data to the question. Your solution returns wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant:

```
SELECT e1.date, e1.file_name, SUM(e1.self) as self, SUM(e1.num_profiles) as num_profiles FROM
(
  SELECT date, file_name, SUM(self) as self, ANY_VALUE(num_profiles)as num_profiles, profile_id FROM ExampleData
  GROUP BY date, file_name, profile_id
) e1 GROUP BY e1.date, e1.file_name;
```